# Regular Expressions: matching a dollar amount

Tags: regex

I'm recently reading "Mastering Regular Expressions"

and on page 24 it says

*" One approach to matching a dollar amount is:
    `\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?`*

blah blah blah .....

One type of value our expression doesn’t match is `$.49` . To solve this, you might be tempted to change the plus to a star, but that doesn’t work. "

What does it mean ?

Since I did check it on some regular expressions test site
and it does matches ?

Comment: Please be more specific.  What does what mean?  What pattern matches what?

Comment: I have changed my typesettings. 
Hope it will be more clear to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `(\.[0-9][0-9])?` is optional too. `\$[0-9]*(\.[0-9][0-9])?` can match a `$` without number after.

A way to be sure to have a number is:

```
\$([0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?|\.[0-9][0-9])
```

Comment: @gkevinyen5418: Yes, I think that `$.49` is a possible value. It doesn't work means that a single `$` is not an acceptable result.